# How to exclude field when writing but not when reading in firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class with constructor and getters:

```
Animal {
   boolean herbivore;
   boolean carnivore;
   boolean omnivore; }
```

And I also have 2 constructors with only herbivore/carnivore fields.

Its possible to use @Exclude on getters when writing in firestore document, so there is no empty fields like this:

```
herbivore: true;
```

instead of like this:

```
carnivore: null;
herbivore: true;
omnivore : null;
```

But, when reading, if a getter is marked with @Exclude, it will not be read.
Is it posible to use @Exclude only when writing and not when reading?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `Exclude` annotation works on both reads and writes. The only way to determine on a per-field level what gets written is to pass it as a `Map` of precisely the values you want.